# paste keycode returned from IE

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to detect user's paste action on the UI.  For example, I need to detect ctrl+V and Shift+insert combo keys.

Based on the information provided from this link, the v key is 86 and insert key is 45.
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

My code work correctly in Firefox but not in IE.  keycode was returned correctly in Firefox.

In IE, when I pressed Ctrl+V, the keycode returned is 17 and the charCode returned is 0.

In IE, when I pressed Shift+Insert, the keycode returned is 16 and the charCode returned is 58.

Is this an IE bug?  Why the keycode and charCode returned are different between IE and FF when the same code is run?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And how would you detect Right click => Paste?

Comment: You may want to use [`onpaste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/paste) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard API doesn't seem to be supported in IE: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/clipboardapi/

First of all `paste` event doesn't work, you should use `beforepaste`.
The `ClipboardEvent` does not exist, the `DragEvent` it's used instead and to get `clipboardData` you access it from `window` not from the event object.

But even so, it doesn't seem to work to access in JavaScript the files/images copied into clipboard.